# Creating subset based on threshold in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I need to subset values in a data frame based on their upper 85-95% bin. Does any one know how I can do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `quantile` to determine which value is the 85 or 95% bin. Next you can use normal R subset syntax to get only the data above that threshold.

```
df[df$value > quantile_thold,]
```

Comment: Thanks! I used quantile as you suggested. quantile(df$value, c(.85, .95))

Comment: If this answered your question, you can mark this answer as the correct one by pressing the green tick mark on the left hand side just below the upvote counter. This signals to the community that this question has been answered, and get's me some rep :).